# Ethernet Signals Complementary

Tags: ethernet, network

I'm doing a little project, regarding a ethernet to fo converter but I have some doubts.
The problem is how TX+ and TX- behaves, are those complementary? I mean if TX+ is high than TX- is low. My other doubt is about how this is adapted to Manchester encoding.

Comment: TX+ & TX- are differential, and Manchester Encoded (or variants thereof, depending on which flavour of Ethernet).  So it's not really "highs" or "lows", but transitions that encode both the data & clock.
What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: My problem is more like, if i put both TX+ and TX- into a differential, than the resulting signal turn on and off a led, oh the other side of the fo I have to regenerate the two signals TX+ and TX- how can I do it?

Comment: Basically, you use a photodiode to detect the light, and use that to drive a differential driver. And I'm sorry to say this, but at your current level of knowledge you're in for a hard time. Even 10 Mbit is tricky to build from scratch, and 100 Mbit requires very high speed techniques and components.

Answer (score 1):

TX+ and TX- are inverses of each other, so when one is high, the other is low and vice versa.
Separate this from the manchester biphase encoding. The TX+, TX- is what's known as differential or balanced signal transmission.  You need a differential line driver to produce these signals. Then at the receiving end you use a differential input receiving amplifier which has two inputs and produces a single output.  And you twist the two cables (V+, V-) between transmitter and receiver, I won't go into all the theory and analysis, but it's a way to reduce noise on the line by using the high common mode rejection ratio of the differential input amplifier.

Balanced line transmission is all about the transmission of analogue signals down wires. Manchester biphase encoding is to do with encoding of digital signals to prepare them for transmission. it's quite a different thing.

If you were to transmit raw binary data down a long cable, where logic 1 is represented by a voltage of 5V, and logic 0 is represented by a voltage of 0 volts, if I were to transmit:
100000001000011 then the issue is there are lots of consecutive bits the same and you don't know where one bit starts or another bit stops, and the whole thing will get out of synchronisation.

What manchester encoding does is encode a clock signal with the data and guarantees that there will  in every bit transmission a change in the voltage level on the line.
The mechanism is based on transistions of the waveform rather than absolute voltage levels can reduce errors.

[image]